# Approximate the integral using Riemann sum

Tags: r

I am trying to approximate an integral of a function f(x) from -inf to +inf using the Riemann sum.

Comment: You are trying how? What have you tried?

Comment: -1: You posted this question earlier (which you deleted now) where you were asked in comments to provide the details.

Comment: Is it the case that `f(x)` takes a value from `-inf` to `+inf`?Then what you are integrating wrt?I am guessing it should be `x` and not `f(x)`

Comment: Yes you are right the integration is wrt x. I have edited it with the intervals -1000 to 1000 instead of -inf to inf.

Comment: You can check the answer, but it doesn't exist. Double check your function

Comment: If I correctly recall from your deleted question, you want the integral of exp(x)/(1+exp(x)), from -inf to +inf. This integral is infinite, since the integrand converges to 1 as x -> +inf.

Answer (score 2):

```
 integrand<-function(x){exp(x)/sum(exp(x))}
    integrate(integrand,lower=-Inf,upper=Inf)
Error in integrate(integrand, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf) : 
  non-finite function value
```

The solution doesn't exist if that is your true function

Comment: No it is not my function but of that nature. It should converge though.

Comment: Thank you all, I should be back after modifying  it and with the real function.

Answer (score 1):

You still haven't clarified the function that you want to integrate.  Can you write the integral that you want to evaluate, in ordinary mathematical notation, forgetting about R for the moment?

Here's what you've written, and why it doesn't make sense:

```
x<- seq(-1000,1000, length=1000)
```

OK, now `x` is vector of length 1000: `(-1000,-997.998,...,997.998,1000)`

```
v <- sum(exp(x))
```

OK, now `v` is equal to the sum of `exp` evaluated for the values on the vector `x`.  And, since `exp(1000)=Inf`, this means that, from the point of view of R, `v` is equal to infinity.

```
f <-(exp(x))/(v)
```

At this point, you have defined `x` to be a vector and `v` to be a scalar, so this expression will set `f` to be a vector of length 1000.  However, since `v` is infinite, then every value on `f` is going to be either `0` or `NaN`.

This all means that

```
integrate(f,  ????  )
```

is meaningless, because `f` is not a function.

If you can write, in ordinary mathematical notation, exactly what integral you want to evaluate, someone will probably be able to help you.

Comment: Just because a term diverges does not imply that an entire function diverges. I suppose it does mean that computing such a term on a finite machine may fail and I guess that is your point.